# How to use Magento 2 cache?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, collection, cache, performance

I have a requirement where, I have huge custom data(around 5000) to display in a page. Currently, I have displayed them in a table and it takes time when I load the page. I want to save the collection in cache and retrieve data from cache. SO that it will load faster. Later on I want to implement filter on cached collection.

Anyone who can help me to implement cache in my requirement?

Answer (score 6):

Add the caching interface loading to the constructor.

```
public function __construct(
   Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
   Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface $cache,
   Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
) {
   $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
   $this->cache = $cache;
   $this->serializer = $serializer;
}
```

For saving the data in the cache

```
$this->cache->save($data, $identifier, $tags, $lifeTime);
```

If you want to save in the array, you need to use the serializer.

```
$data = $this->serializer->unserialize($data) 

$identifier - unique identifier of the stored information block.

$tags = array of tags - may be empty.
```

$lifeTime - (in seconds) - by default null, it always appears in the cache and valid.

To get data from the cache

```
$this->cache->load($identifier)
```

If there is no data or the lifetime has expired, the method returns false.

Convert the data after receiving it from the cache, if you have it serialized before adding

Comment: why do you need to make the serializer null in the constructor and then instantiate it via object manager? This is done in the core just for backwards compatibility when a new parameter is added to the constructor. But in your own code you don't need it. You can just leave in the constructor signature `Json $serializer`  and in the method `$this->serializer = $serializer`

Comment: Got your point, thank @Marius